# Question about a specific syntax in while in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm looking for a way to check the next char in a string without incrementing the string, using the specific syntax of my while.

I tried some `++str` but it increments the string.

```
void  test(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
         if(*str++ != ' ')
             ft_putchar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

I would like to `putchar` only if the next char isn't a space.

You guys have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry for the no incrementation, I don't know why it is displayed without the incrementation

Comment: Why do you need to check the next character? The correct answer is to write the loop so that it makes sense for whatever you are trying to do. Are you trying to remove spaces while printing?

Comment: So what should happen if the next char **is** a space? Abort the loop? Skip the current character?

Comment: It's a part of a bigger exercice, that I already know how to do but I want to do the exercice with a different syntax. In this exercice I have to return a char** stocking each word in a char* whitout the spaces. I would use this to count words by checking if next char is a separator.

Comment: Simply count the separators then? `while(*str != '\0') { if(*str == ' ') count++; str++; }`.

Comment: The fact is that if I have the string : "Hello           *space* *space* *space*         yo", the function should return 2 words

Comment: So I have to check the current char, and the next one to make sure it's a word

Comment: No, you `strcmp` from the start of a character until the next space, then store the results somehow.

Comment: To do the exercice I have to create all the function I want to use, and I can't use more than 5 diffrent functions(including ft_putchar). So I prefer not using strcmp (even if I know how to write it) I only can use malloc without recoding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]
Based on what was said in the comments you might want to look at [strstr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) to look for duplicates once you break the string into words.
Also for breaking into words you might want to check out [strsep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html).

If you want to check the next character you should do so.

```
void  test(char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if(*(str + 1) != ' ')
             ft_putchar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

The syntax `*(str + 1)` works due to how pointer arithmetics work, since str is a char * it will advance to the next char before being dereferenced. As Nikos C. observed in the comments `str[1]` also works and it's a "cleaner" syntax.

This is the simplest syntax that checks the next character, assuming your string is 0-terminated due to the while there is no need to check if another character exists since the while will not be entered otherwise.

Comment: Or just `str[1]`.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to print the last character before a space though?

Comment: @NikosC. good obervation, hope you don't mind if I add it to the answer

Comment: Oh thanks ! I was searching for a long time. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: @Lundin I don't want to but it was in the requirements stated by OP

Comment: @xception Which is why we need to fish for what they actually want before posting an answer. This is a typical "XY question".

Comment: @AlexandredeTemmerman if you're happy with one of the offered solutions you should mark the answer as accepted, otherwise people will keep responding to the question and waste their time reading your requirements for no good reason. Typically saying you should accept an answer as soon as it meets your requirements for the question to let people help others with their time.

Comment: Ok okay, I'll do that immediately !

Comment: First question on SO that's why I didn't do it

Comment: @AlexandredeTemmerman I just edited it moments after you accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to putchar only if the next char isn't a space.

You could use

```
         if(*(str + 1) != ' ')
             ft_putchar(*str);
```

But that's 100% equivalent to this, which I find clearer:

```
         if(str[1] != ' ')
             ft_putchar(*str);
```

Moreover, I suspect that you also want to avoid outputting the string terminator, so I would probably structure the whole thing slightly differently:

```
    if (*str) {
        while (str[1]) {
            if (str[1] != ' ') {
                ft_putchar(*str);
            }
            str++;
        }
        str++;  // because the original loop leaves str pointing to the terminator
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `for` loop is more suitable in this situation. Also the parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the string is not changed in the function.

The function can look the following way

```
void  test( const char *s )
{
    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( *( s + 1 ) != ' ' ) ft_putchar( *s );
    }
}
```

The expression `*( s + 1 )` can be substituted for `s[1]`.

Or even like this

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

void  test( const char *s )
{
    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )s[1] ) ) ft_putchar( *s );
    }
}
```

If you want to use exactly the while loop then just write for example

```
void  test( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s )
    {
        if ( *( s + 1 ) != ' ' ) ft_putchar( *s );
        ++s;
    }
}
```

Or

```
void  test( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s )
    {
        if ( !isspace( ( unsigned char )s[1] ) ) ft_putchar( *s );
        ++s;
    }
}
```

Or you can write the function also the following way

```
void  test( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s )
    {
        if ( *++s != ' ' ) ft_putchar( s[-1] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use for loops. Only while, I sould have write it sorry.

Comment: @AlexandredeTemmerman See my updated post. Pay attention to the last function implementation.